# How to write a function instead of using the built in Object.keys() method?

Tags: javascript

How would I write the code below as function and not using the built in Object.keys() method? Thank you!

```
var obj = { Name: 'Joe', Age: 18, pass: true };
console.log(Object.keys(obj)); // =>  [ 'Name', 'Age', 'pass' ]
```

Comment: See polyfill [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
function getKeys(obj){
  return Object.keys(obj)
}
```

or

```
function getKeys(){
    var keys = [];
    for (var key in foo) {
        keys.push(key);
    }
    return keys;
}
```

or you can do

```
Object.prototype.getKeys = function(o, f, ctx) {
    return Object.keys(o);
}
// obj.getKeys() => [ 'Name', 'Age', 'pass' ]
```

Comment: Is it possible to write as a function without using the Object.keys in the code at all?

Comment: @learninghowtocode you mean you want something like `obj.getKeys()` ??

Comment: why are you so against Object.keys?

Comment: The third one doesn't allow for `obj.getKeys()`. You would have to set the function to `Object.prototype.getKeys`

Comment: @4castle are you sure?? i use it in an application, and it's work. let me check, thanks for mention

Comment: LOL! I'm not against Object Keys I'm just not supposed to use them to learn at the moment. :) Thanks @Shayan your second response was what I was looking for.  Thanks for everyone's help!! Much appreciated!

Comment: you miss [`Object#hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) check for an equvalent of [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and some newer checks for it.

Answer (score 0):

@Shayan's response here is what I was looking for:

```
function getKeys(){
    var keys = [];
    for (var key in foo) {
    keys.push(key);
    }
    return keys;
 }
```

Comment: Rather than post a duplicate answer, you can click the check mark beside an answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful tip!